# Puppeteer screenshot not rendering correct fonts on webpage?

Tags: puppeteer

I am using Puppeeter to take a screenshot, and not matter what I do, the text on the page is never rendered in the correct font. I've done a bunch of research and I'm including a number of flags that folks mention might help with fonts. I am running puppeteer in a docker container in the cloud.

Here is my code snippet. On the page where I'm taking the screenshot, I have

```
const generateImage = async () =>{
           const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox','--font-render-hinting=none']});
           const page = await browser.newPage();
           await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36");
           await page.setViewport({width:1200,height:1200,});
           await page.goto(url, {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});
          
           await page.screenshot({path:`./${form.zoneid}-${form.formid}.jpg`,type: 'jpeg', quality: 100,});
           await browser.close()
       }
       await generateImage()
```

This is the URL I'm trying to take a screen shot of:
https://dev.graceblocks.com/form?x=MTI0fGdyYWNlYmxvY2tzLTF8NDU=&mode=preview&social=1

Notice the header text is Arial Black, but the screenshot is always defaulting to Times new Roman...so somehow it seems like it's ignoring the font setting. I thought Arial Black is a standard web font that would be recognized by any browser?

Is there some other setting I need to set in order for this screenshot to render the proper font?

Comment: For me, it is Arial Black on the screenshot, Puppeteer 9.0.0, Chromium 91.0.4469.0 (r869685), Windows 10. If I run the code on https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/ the font still looks OK. What is your Chrome/Chromium version? If you use `headless: false` will the font be the correct one?

Comment: I'm deploying this on a linux Docker file. I chedked my package.json, and it's using :  "puppeteer": "^8.0.0",

Comment: I am not specifying a chrome install inside Docker file, maybe I should? I thought Puppetteer was the chrome version?

Comment: No, that's fine. If you have pptr 8.0.0 then Chromium is 90.0.4427.0 (r856583). The page you are visiting specifies `font-family: Arial;` and Arial is a Windows-specific font. Mostly Linux fallback to other sans-serif fonts but in your case either the Linux version or another setting in the Docker container makes the font Times New Roman-like.

Comment: So, was in middle of testing. Arial actually works ok. But Arial Black does not, it ends up showing as Times New Roman. Ultimately, I want the font to be Roboto Black (that's where I started), but how would I set that up? Do I need to install this in my docker file? Any clues how?

Comment: Sorry, I will not know that, unfortunately. But if it is a site that you are developing you could use Roboto Black from Google Fonts (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) to ensure it look the same in Docker as in other environments.